# Verilog circular registers, how do they work?

Tags: verilog

Question on circular registers:

CODE:

```
reg [7:0] value1;

reg [7:0] value2;

value1 = 50;

value2 = value1 - 255;
```

QUESTION:

Will value2=0 or will value2=205 ??

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

```
reg [7:0] value1;
reg [7:0] value2;

always @* begin
  value1 = 50;
  value2 = value1 - 255;
end
```

`value2` will be 205. The second blocking assignment happens after the first one, so when value2 is being assigned to, value1 has already a known value (50).

```
reg [7:0] value1;
reg [7:0] value2;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  value1 <= 50;
  value2 <= value1 - 255;
end
```

`value2` will be 205 after the second clk rising edge. Both assignments are non blocking. After the first rising edge (the first time the `always` is evaluated) `value1` is 50, and `value2` is undetermined, because it's assigned at the same time as `value1`, and at that time, `value1` has not yet a known value.

After the second clock rising edge, `value1` doesn't change (it's assigned 50 again), and `value2` gets 205, because it's evaluated using the previous value of `value1`, which was 50 already.

Answer (score 0):

Neither 0, nor 205, but 51!

value1 and value2 are both unsigned, therefore, the result should also be unsigned:

Value1 = 00110010, -255 = (11111111111111111111111100000001)_base2, value2 = (00110011)_base2 = ( 51)_base10

Here is [my test module](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2f7):

```
module test;
 reg [7:0]  value1;
 reg [7:0]  value2;


initial begin
  value1 = 50;
  value2 = value1 - 255;
  $display ("Value1 = %b, -255 = (%b)_base2, value2 = (%b)_base2 = (%d)_base10", value1, -255, value2, value2);
end
endmodule
```

Comment: `logic` is not a datatype supported by Verilog. This question has not been `Systemverilog` tagged.